# Multiple ELMAH Filter Conditions

Tags: model-view-controller, elmah

I wanted to know if there is a way that I can write ELMAH to filter out error logging under the following logic:

If the error is a 404 on `favicon.ico` **OR** the error is 404 on `/1.xml` **OR** the error is 404 on `/2.xml`

I have found the way to just do it on the `favicon.ico` as shown:

```
 <errorFilter>
  <test>
    <and>
      <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
      <regex binding="Context.Request.ServerVariables['URL']" pattern="/favicon\.ico(\z|\?)" />
    </and>
  </test>
</errorFilter>
```

But for some reason, I cannot understand how to do it for the `OR` conditions. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The following should do the trick or otherwise get you started:

```
<errorFilter>
  <test>
    <and>
      <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
      <or>
        <regex binding="Context.Request.ServerVariables['URL']" 
               pattern="/favicon\.ico(\z|\?)" />
        <regex binding="Context.Request.ServerVariables['URL']" 
               pattern="/[1-2]\.xml(\z|\?)" />
      </or>
    </and>
  </test>
</errorFilter>
```

Basically, this will filter errors where the HTTP status code is 404 *and* one of the regular expressions patterns grouped under the `or` element match the request URL.

Comment: Hello Atif, I tried this and it doesn't seem to work. I want to make sure I'm handling this right. Here is how I throw the exception when I cannot resolve the URL.  throw new HttpException(404,
                    String.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found or it does not implement IController.",
                        requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));

Comment: Do you have the Elmah.ErrorFilterModule module registered and does it appear after all other ELMAH modules in the modules section?

Comment: Yes I have everything configured correctly. Noticed an interesting thing, the declarative web.config filtering doesn't work, but the programmatic part does work. I have resolved this using the programmatic approach, but would love to hear any further insights. If I just use the 404 block w/o any OR/regex conditions (i.e. block all 404s), that works too. I will do some further research and add my comment if I find anything else.

Comment: What does the programmatic version look like? Are you also using the same regular expression pattern to look for URL matches?