# Error filters in web.config are ignored when using ErrorLog_Filtering with ELMAH

Tags: elmah

I have implemented an elmah filter that removes sensitive information from the exception being recording using a method similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628389/in-elmah-with-mvc-3-how-can-i-hide-sensitive-form-data-from-the-error-log) by overriding `ErrorLog_Filtering` in Global.asax.

This works great, but it ignores the filters I have setup in web.config via the `<errorFilter>` elements.

Is there some way I can apply my custom sanitization filter, but still make use of the filtering specified in web.config as well?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here -- it was as simple as checking if `e.Dismissed` has already been set (for example, by the error filter module) before processing/recording the exception it in my santization helper.